# External HDD still mounted even after reboot

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, mount

I'm running a Windows 10 PC. I have mounted an external HDD. Everything worked as expected. I powered down the Windows 10 PC and removed the HDD only after the power was off.  Now that I turn Windows 10 PC on again, Windows still shows that the HDD is mounted. I can even "access" the drive (still unplugged), but all the folders are empty.

Now that I plug the external HDD back in, Windows won't mount the HDD because it thinks that the drive is already mounted.

Any ideas how I can access the REAL external HDD again?

Comment: See if opening a command prompt and typing this works:  `mountvol <drive letter> /D`

Comment: You can also try a full (normal) reboot. Start, run (as admin), shutduwn /s.  (likely cause, windows 10 powerdown or shutdown is a suspend to kernel-ish thing, keeping information in order to allow a faster boot).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with the following steps:

1. Turn on PC
2. Sign in to user account (drive is still there)
3. Start -> Sign out (NOT "Shut down")
4. Sign in with a DIFFERENT user account. (not sure if this step was necessary but it worked for me)
5. Sign out again
6. Sign in with the original user account

Drive is gone.